# collapsable tableview with section and row with header and footer

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

After searching so many links and GitHub demo I didn't find my solution so I post this question, I need tableview expandable and collapsable and its row with header and footer like:

[image: tableviw with expandable row]

Comment: share you code @riddhi

Comment: I am using FTFoldingTableView demo for  Folding cells but I can not display row with its header and footer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put Puma Shoes and Price in Section Header and try to manage the below content in rows for the section.
You can manage last row as footer.
so for indexpath.row == 0 add row reqd. id reqd qty etc

so on click on minus(-) button on section header you can change row height to 0. also change the footer height to 0.

Comment: puma shoes is already in section header and all value are in row but now I want only put req.id , req .qty row and its footer , so I will try your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Give one of these libraries a try:

https://github.com/jeantimex/CollapsibleTableSectionViewController

https://github.com/rob-nash/CollapsibleTable

Answer (score 0):

You can try CollapseClick, will be a better option for your requirement

https://github.com/bennyguitar/CollapseClick